# How to share app.config between parent console application and ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, console-application

**Scenario**

- I have a web application project and a console project.
- The console project is used to send reports in batch and has settings in
  app.config pertaining to email.
- Sometimes methods in the console project are call from the web application.

After deploying the website, I make sure that I copy *consoleProject.exe.config* and place it in the same bin folder as *consoleProject.exe*.

**Problem**

After deployment, If I make changes to *consoleProject.exe.config*, the changes are not recognized when calling methods in *consoleProject.exe* from the web application.

Is this default app.config file only referred to when the actual app is being executed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're calling code in the console app from the web app, it is treated the same as if you were calling a dll, and your web.config is used.

Similarly, if you call from the console application into code within a web app dll, the app.exe.config file will be used.

Comment: So if I create an additional config file for the console app, say settings.config, and put the shared settings in there, will that always be referred to?

Comment: Is there a web.config file in your web application?  That's where your settings should go.  It's the web equivalent to app.config.

Comment: Yes, but I can't put the settings in there because the console application executes every day, as a batch job, totally independent of the web site.

Comment: In that case you need two different config files - one for the web application and one for the console application.  BTW, you should seriously consider putting the common code into a library dll, instead of calling into web app code from a console app.

Comment: I agree on the separate dll and I'd have done the same - I'll refactor if I have time. I've tested replicating a setting in both the console and web app and that works. The problem is that settings have to be duplicated. Is there an easy way to share settings? Note: The settings never have to be accessed from the web application.

Comment: It looks like I could by using: <appSettings file=”c:\commonSettings.config”>. The problem is that this requires an absolute path.

Comment: Is there really a duplication concern if you don't use the web.config settings?  Just ignore web.config and put your settings in app.config.

Comment: But then that gets back to my original problem. If the settings are only in app.config then any changes made to app.exe.config are ignored when calling a method from the web site application.